# Find the mass function of $Z = X + Y$ where $X,Y$ are discrete uniform.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, both being equally likely to take any value in $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$. I know that 
$$P(Z=z)=\sum P(X=x,Y=x−z)$$

and by the independence of $X$ and $Y$,

$$\sum P(X=x,Y=x−z)=\sum P(X=x)P(Y=x−z)$$

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it should be $Y=z-x$ and not $Y=x-z$ as you have it. Second, you should say where does $Z$ take its values. Indeed, the possible values of $Z$ are $0\le Z\le 2n$. Hence, you need a case discrimination, depending on whether $z\le n$ or $z>n$

1. For $0\le z\le n$
   \begin{align}P(Z=z)=\dots=\sum_{x=0}^z P(X=x)P(Y=z-x)&=\sum_{x=0}^z \frac1{n+1}\frac1{n+1}=\frac{z+1}{(n+1)^2}\end{align}
2. For $n+1\le z \le 2n$
   \begin{align}P(Z=z)=\dots=\sum_{x=z-n}^n P(X=x)P(Y=z-x)&=\sum_{x=z-n}^n \frac1{n+1}\frac1{n+1}=\frac{2n-z+1}{(n+1)^2}\end{align}

Check for (major) mistakes: All probabilities should sum up to $1$: 
\begin{align}\sum_{z=1}^{2n}P(Z=z)&=\frac1{(n+1)^2}\left(\sum_{z=0}^n(z+1)+\sum_{z=n+1}^{2n}(2n-z+1)\right)=\\[0.3cm]&=\frac1{(n+1)^2}\left((n+1)+\sum_{z=0}^nz+\sum_{z=1}^{n}z\right)=1\end{align} where for the second sum, I observed that for $z=n+1$ to $z=2n$ the inner term is just $n, n-1,n-2,\dots1$. I also used that $$\sum_{z=0}^nz=\sum_{z=1}^n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$